# Picking between SVD and Gauss Newton for least sqaures error minimization

Tags: least-squares, svd, error-function

I have seen examples where least squares error minimization has been done using SVD. One such example is camera calibration. The system to solve is

$M \times p = \omega$

Ideally $\omega$ has to be zero (equivalent of ground truth). The $p$ vector is a vector of 9 camera parameters such as $p_11, p_12....p_33$. The system is linear wrt parameters.

However, in the case of graph optimization for SLAM problems, I have seen Gauss Newton being used. In this case:

$e = z - f(x)$

Here e is the error, z is the ground truth and f is the non-linear function based on parameters x. I understand that Gauss-Newton is suitable when there is a good initial guess available and when the error function is smooth near the minima.

1) However, are there any methods to identify which algorithm is suitable for a particular problem?

2) Is it right to say that SVD is more suitable for linear least squares and Gauss Newton for non-linear least squares?

Comment: I think your point 2 is correct. (Although other methods can also be considered for either linear least squares or nonlinear least squares. For example, there are iterative methods for large scale linear least squares problems, and for nonlinear least squares problems Levenberg-Marquardt is also popular.) It's not clear how the SVD would be used for a nonlinear problem, except perhaps to solve linear subproblems at each iteration of Gauss-Newton or another iterative method.

Comment: The SVD minimizes the 2 norm, so it is used for least squares. newton's method is used for solving non-linear systems.